# Delete files with specific filename pattern in directory with all extension using python

Tags: python, file, file-system

**Preamble**

The first following code explains the context.

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(comuni)

#I call a vector in QGIS that is displayed as map that I am interested to build df7
lyr2 = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('ac_002_1_v1_1_limiti_giurisdizionali_indicativi_comuni')[0]

#from the vector ac_002_1_v1_1_limiti_giurisdizionali_indicativi_comuni I create daaframe with pandas df7 that 
#represents the unique values of the attribute of the field 'comune min' deprived from the disturbing character '/'
cols2 = ['comune_min'] 
datagen2 = ([f[col2] for col2 in cols2] for f in lyr2.getFeatures())
df5 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=datagen2, columns=cols2)
df6 = df5['comune_min'].str.replace('/',' ')
df7 = df6.unique()
print(df7)

#I compare df7 with df4 that has been created with the same method but should be a subset of df7. So, df8 is the difference of the two dataframe
#df8 is the dataframe that contains the string that lead to the deletion of the file. In other words, 
#if the file df8 contain "comune_eccedente" have to be deleted.
df8=set(df7).difference(set(df4))
```

Here what happens when I print df8.

```
{'Neggio', 'Cerentino', 'Grancia', 'Orselina', 'Campo (Vallemaggia)', 'Bedretto', 'Agno', 'Bosco Gurin', 'Pollegio', 'Origlio', 'Personico', 'Vernate', 'Muralto', 'Ponte Capriasca', 'Breggia', 'Lavertezzo', 'Cureglia', 'Arogno', 'Cugnasco-Gerra', 'Faido', 'Porza', 'Giornico', 'Caslano', 'Riva San Vitale', 'Muzzano', 'Prato Leventina', 'Magliaso', 'Pura', 'Morcote', 'Cadenazzo Monteceneri', 'Curio', 'Paradiso', 'Lamone', 'Arbedo-Castione', 'Bodio', 'Quinto', 'Comano', 'Novaggio', 'Savosa', 'Verzasca', 'Lavizzara', 'Bedigliora', 'Bissone', 'Massagno', 'Sorengo', 'Canobbio', 'Dalpe', 'Isone', 'Acquarossa', 'Serravalle', 'Miglieglia', 'Lumino', 'Biasca', 'Gambarogno', 'Vezia', 'Linescio'}
```

**Problem and code to be edited**

Here is part of my folder "./Spedire".
[image]

Now I want to delete all files that contain in the filename a part that is an item of df8 called "comune_eccedente". If you look at the image above of the folder, the file "zp_Neggio.xlsx" and "zp_Neggio.gpkg" have to be deleted because "Neggio" is an item of the df8 and is contained in the filename.
You should now focusing on the following case, which is the code that I want to edit in properlier way.

```
#At the moment I reconstruct the entire path
#and I delete the file based on the entire filename for specific extensions. 
for comune_eccedente in df8: 
    try:
        my_path ='./Spedire/'
        file_name1 = 'zp_'+str(comune_eccedente)+'.gpkg'
        complete_path = my_path+file_name1
        os.remove(complete_path)
    except:
        pass
for comune_eccedente in df8: 
    try:
        file_name2 = 'zp_'+str(comune_eccedente)+'.xlsx'
        complete_path2 = my_path+file_name2
        os.remove(complete_path2)
    except:
        pass
```

I am unsatisfied because I could simply find the match between the filename and the string "comune_eccedente" and delete ALL the files that have the match independently of their extension instead of creating specific iteration depending of the extension as I do in the code above. If in future some pdf file will be created, I have to create again specific code "try....except" for pdf and so on. That is not good.

I want a code that only look at the "comune_eccedente" item such as "Neggio" and delete all files that are inside the directory that contain "Neggio" in their filename.

Comment: Where is `df8` defined?  This looks incomplete.

Comment: Is `df8` a Pandas dataframe? If so that will suggest a very different solution from one where it's a plain iterable

Comment: df8 is a pandas dataframe!

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Thank you for clarifying about `df8`. Please [edit] the post to include more complete code, including import statements.

Comment: @Reinderien
I have edited the post to explain better.

Comment: That's useful (and probably enough for a review). However, the quality of the review will improve if you post all of your code - the code size limit is quite high.

Comment: @Reinderien
the code is 300 line long. Your suggestion would give more trouble than it's worth. If I added all you get lost. If I tried to select again more code I employ too much time and the suggested correction would influence the entire 300 line code. So, I am happy even if you improve only the last code.

Comment: 300 lines is not enough to get us lost - there are some people on this forum with quite a lot of experience, and the more context you provide, the more value you'll get out of the question.

Comment: @Reinderien ok, but in my opionion the review should be done not at this stage but when the entire jobs is finished. At the moment I will ask this specific question on stack overflow. I will be back with the request review for the entire code when I have finished.

Comment: This is a more appropriate site than StackOverflow to ask for review, so I don't think that would be an entirely good idea. I'll try my best to answer this question as-is.

Comment: I prefer to do a review when my code is ended. Then I will show my final entire code. I will delete this post and I will return at the end. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

Don't name your dataframe variables `df1`, `df2` etc. Give them meaningful names describing what they contain.

Don't use `set()` on a dataframe. Instead, use something like [Index.difference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html).

It's good for your data to contain Italian text, but non-desirable for your variable names and schema (column names, etc.) to contain Italian text. For better or worse, English is the language of international technical collaboration. As such, `comune_eccedente` should be called something like `surplus_municipality`.

Never bare `try`/`except`, and in this case don't `try` at all. Use `pathlib` and `unlink`:

```
from pathlib import Path

municipalities = {'Neggio', 'Cerentino', 'Grancia', 'Orselina', 'Campo (Vallemaggia)', 'Bedretto', 'Agno', 'Bosco Gurin',
       'Pollegio', 'Origlio', 'Personico', 'Vernate', 'Muralto', 'Ponte Capriasca', 'Breggia', 'Lavertezzo',
       'Cureglia', 'Arogno', 'Cugnasco-Gerra', 'Faido', 'Porza', 'Giornico', 'Caslano', 'Riva San Vitale', 'Muzzano',
       'Prato Leventina', 'Magliaso', 'Pura', 'Morcote', 'Cadenazzo Monteceneri', 'Curio', 'Paradiso', 'Lamone',
       'Arbedo-Castione', 'Bodio', 'Quinto', 'Comano', 'Novaggio', 'Savosa', 'Verzasca', 'Lavizzara', 'Bedigliora',
       'Bissone', 'Massagno', 'Sorengo', 'Canobbio', 'Dalpe', 'Isone', 'Acquarossa', 'Serravalle', 'Miglieglia',
       'Lumino', 'Biasca', 'Gambarogno', 'Vezia', 'Linescio'}

#At the moment I reconstruct the entire path
#and I delete the file based on the entire filename for specific extensions. 
for surplus_municipality in municipalities:
    stem = Path('Spedire') / f'zp_{surplus_municipality}'
    stem.with_suffix('.gpkg').unlink(missing_ok=True)
    stem.with_suffix('.xlsx').unlink(missing_ok=True)
```

Comment: ok, I see that you have answered. Thank you. A preliminar question: why I have to avoid try/except?

Comment: Logic by exception is, is general, a bad idea. And writing `except` with no specific exception is especially bad: it masks a whole world of exceptions that would otherwise tell you crucial failures of the program, and also prevents the proper functioning of mechanisms like Ctrl+C (the "break" signal).

Comment: A last question: why don't you use os.remove instead of unlink?
thank you very much

Comment: `os.` is an older, non-object-oriented filesystem interface. `pathlib` is object-oriented and more easily manipulates paths.

Comment: how can you know if os. is younger or older than pathlib. Is there a list of "deprecating" module or a suggested good way to find out?

Comment: It's not deprecated, but it is older. `os` has been around for basically all of Python and `pathlib` wasn't available until Python 3